# cast from chart to chartObject

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

In VBA(Excel), I have an object of type Chart. I need to copy the corresponding graph into a powerpoint file. I don't know how to do it, so I wonder if it is possible to cast/convert from chart to chartObject. If yes, how do we do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can usually copy the object in Excel then PasteSpecial into the PowerPoint slide's shapes collection and supply the paste type you want (embedded, linked, picture, etc).  Pasting as Shape or Default gives you a PPT type 3/Chart object.  Pasting as OLE Object gives you an embedded or linked Excel chart object.

Answer (score 2):

`Chart` has a `Parent` property which gives you a reference to the hosting `ChartObject`.

```
? typename(activesheet.chartobjects(1).chart.parent) '>> ChartObject
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case if the `Chart` object is a direct child of the Workbook as a 'chart sheet'.

Comment: @GWD - good point: I was thinking of charts on worksheets.  I always forget the other kind...

Answer (score 0):

And here's a snippet of code; this assumes that the Excel chart has already been copied to the clipboard and that you want to put the chart on the first slide.  Uncomment whichever line suits your purposes:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
   ' .PasteSpecial ppPasteShape  ' 11
   ' .PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault ' 0
   ' .PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject ' 10
End With
```